Flutter is not updating cubit state in ui
in note app I want to delete note from list in hive and update  UI by Cubit state in the same time (Deletion is done by a button in the note itself ) But this does not happen directly in UI until I click Restart the application (Knowing that the requested status is returned in Clonsol)
What is the solution to this problem?
my Cubite class
class NotesCubit extends Cubit<NotesState> {
  NotesCubit(super.initialState);
  List<NoteModel>? notes;
  fetchnotes() async {
    emit(NotesLoading());
    var notesBox = Hive.box<NoteModel>(noteBox);
    notes = notesBox.values.toList();
    emit(NotesSuccess());
  }
}

main class
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider(create: (context) => AddNoteCubit(AddNoteInitial())),
        BlocProvider(
          create: (context) => NotesCubit(NotesInintial()),
        )
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData(brightness: Brightness.dark, fontFamily: 'Poppins'),
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Scaffold(
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionbutton(),
          backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 39, 14, 54),
          body: Notes_View_body(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

delete Button :
 IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(
          size: 20,
          FontAwesomeIcons.trash     
               color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () async {
                    note.delete();
                    context.read<NotesCubit>().fetchnotes();
                  },
                ),


Are you using BlocBuilder to present the list on ui? can you include more sample snippet that will reproduce the same error?

yes I using BlocBuilder to present the list on ui
in this way :
 BlocBuilder(
        bloc: NotesCubit(NotesInintial()),
        builder: (context, state) {
          List<NoteModel> notes =
              BlocProvider.of<NotesCubit>(context).notes ?? [];
          return ListView.builder(
            physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return ListTileItem(
                note: notes[index],
              );
            },
            itemCount: notes.length,
          );
        },
      ),```
